# Options displayed depending of previous drop down list selection

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple dropdown list and I would like to display the options depending of the option selected in the previous drop down list.

```
    <select name="parent1">
       <option value="">--Select a Location--</option>';
       <?php       
          foreach($alllocations as $elementlocations)
          {                                        
             if($elementlocations["parent1"]=="no" and $elementlocations["parent2"]=="no")
             {
              echo'
              <option class="'.$elementlocations["system"].'" value="'.$elementlocations["generalID"].'">'.$elementlocations["name"].'</option>';
             }
          }
      ?>
</select>
<select name="parent2">
   <option value="">--Select a Location--</option>
   <?php       
     foreach($alllocations as $elementlocations)
     {
       if($elementlocations["parent1"]!="no" and $elementlocations["parent2"]=="no")
       {
         echo'
          <option class="'.$elementlocations["parent1"].'" value="'.$elementlocations["generalID"].'">'.$elementlocations["name"].'</option>';
       }
     }
   ?>
</select>
<select name="parent3">
   <option value="">--Select a Location--</option>
   <?php       
      foreach($alllocations as $elementlocations)
      {
         if($elementlocations["parent1"]!="no" and $elementlocations["parent2"]!="no")
         {
           echo'
            <option class="'.$elementlocations["parent3"].'" value="'.$elementlocations["generalID"].'">'.$elementlocations["name"].'</option>';
         }
      }
  ?>
```

The idea would be to take the value selected in the first list and display only the options of the second list for which the class match the value selected in the first list. I found some Js but I cannot manage to make them work for my objective.

Edit:

Well I was told jQuery was easy and fast to learn so I tried ... idead it took me 2 hours to learn enough to solve my issue. JQuery looks hard but in fact it is SUPER fast to learn (it include a few lines more for a new drop down list.)

Issue Solved

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#selectsystem').on('change', function(){
                        if( $('#selectsystem').val() != '') {
                            $('#sublocations').show();
                            $('#parent1').show();
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $('#sublocations').hide();
                            $('#parent1').hide();
                          }
                    });
                    $('#parent1').on('change', function(){
                        if( $('#parent1').val() != '') {
                            $('#parent2').show();
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $('#parent2').hide();
                            $('#parent3').hide();
                          }
                    });
                    $('#parent2').on('change', function(){
                        if( $('#parent2').val() != '') {
                            $('#parent3').show();
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $('#parent3').hide();
                          }
                    });
                    $('#selectsystem').on('change', function(){
                        $('#parent1 option').not('.'+ this.value).hide();
                        $('.emptyselection').show();
                        $('.'+ this.value).show();
                    });
                    $('#parent1').on('change', function(){
                        $('#parent2 option').not('.'+ this.value).hide();
                        $('.emptyselection').show();
                        $('.'+ this.value).show();
                    });
                    $('#parent2').on('change', function(){
                        $('#parent3 option').not('.'+ this.value).hide();
                        $('.emptyselection').show();
                        $('.'+ this.value).show();
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Look into jquery, it will make doing this much easier than raw javascript (if you are not versed in full raw javascript). Also, you can go either ajax with pulling data, or fill js arrays and utilize those. Depends on how many options may be spilling out from the foreachs you have.

Comment: In other words, there are a few major branch points to go with this... and if you try something, then we can better help you figure out whats not working right. But just asking us to write all the code for you, is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: the problem is I can just understand slightly JS, and do basic things but don't know jquery and even less about Ajax. And as this is probably the only thing that would require ajax it feels silly to put all my work aside for month while learning Ajax just for that... in the same time it is a key element of my website and cannot give up on this :(

Comment: The beauty of jquery is .... is sooo quick to learn. Almost in a day you can find hundreds of examples of code to do basic ajax calls and manipulate selects. I used to know oldschool JS, then I began using jquery, and now I've forgotten how to do oldschool JS ! ;)

Comment: Indead it is Super easy took me 2 hours to go from scratch to do the script I needed (Edited in my post).
Thanks for telling me it was so easy I would not have dared trying to learn it right now if you didn't tell me it was so easy.